# forms->is there a way to disable the enter key so they have to click submit

Tags: php, html, forms

My situation is that I want to use input text but need the enter key disabled. To submit the form they must click on the submit button.

Is there a way to disable the enter so it doesn't submit?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your submit button, bind the following code:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
   var x = event.which;
   if (x === 13) {
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```